# Where did the name Nimitseahpah come from?

Tags: short-stories, inspiration, nancy-etchemendy

In the January 2004 issue of *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, they ran a story called "Nimitseahpah", by Nancy Etchemendy. 'Nimitseahpah' is the name of the Paiute statue that's part of the story:

> "It has a powerful name. Nimitseahpah. The Paiutes never say it aloud. They only whisper it, same as the old miners," I heard Nev say.
>   <sub>Page 17</sub>

But where is this name from? Is it a real name from somewhere, or did Nancy just make it up?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but to me it seems somewhat reminiscent of Lovecraft's [Nyarlathotep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyarlathotep) (and a bit of googling suggests that the genre of this short story has some overlap with Lovecraft's work as well, so there's a chance she's familiar with his work).

Answer (score 5):

In an [interview](https://www.nightmare-magazine.com/nonfiction/author-spotlight-nancy-etchemendy/) for *Nightmare Magazine* in April of this year, Etchemendy states that:

> Nimitseahpah, by the way, is a Paiute word that is usually translated
> as “God.” But the old Paiutes weren’t monotheists. The word is more
> accurately translated as “the wellspring from which all things come.”
> Or so I’m told.